# Media query and high resolution smartphones

Tags: responsive-design

First I apologize for posting a question that is discussed in past.
After searching for days I still don't understand how should I find out that a device with 1k or even higher resolution is a smartphone.
For example my monitor is 1280 x 1024 and I want to have 3 columns on desktop screens but how should I know that a 1k and higher res belongs to a smartphone that I need to shrink my layout to one column.

Comment: First of all, _why_ would you want to go for a one column layout if the screen res is higher than 1000 px …?

Comment: HI CBroe. Each column contains different images and texts and despite the high resolution it is still considered an small screen. I want to make it easier to read without zooming in or out.